In which country can I get asylum from Ukraine and Russia?
In which country can I get asylum from Ukraine and Russia?
I have lived in the occupied territories of Ukraine. In Russia, the top leadership has serious claims against me, which is why the special services have taken me up. I moved to Europe, but Ukraine exchanged me from Russia as it was profitable for it. The EU countries support Ukraine, so they will not provide me with international protection. I was also denied a visa to the USA in Poland.
I earned money working remotely through the Internet - a freelance programmer.
Is there any country that could grant me asylum?

"Could" is the wrong question. Most countries can grant asylum to anyone if their government wants to. The right question is "will" and that depends on the details of your case. You should not reveal the details on a website like this. For this reason, your question is not suitable for Stackexchange.

@o.m. Please don't delete. Maybe someone here has experience of a similar situation.

If you have the nationality of both Ukraine and Russia, then your asylum claim will need to show that you require protection from both countries.  So you'll need to find a country that will accept this.  The refugee convention also allows countries to refuse to grant asylum to people who have committed serious crimes.  Thus, if either country has accused you of crimes, you would have to show that the charges are unfounded or political in nature.  There's no universally agreed framework for this, so this may be the critical consideration.  Have you tried UNHCR? Can you not stay in Poland?

@phoog, compare his previous question. He does not feel safe there.

@o.m. I see, thanks, I had forgotten that detail.  The next steps then seem to be to identify a country that won't extradite him to Russia, go there, and apply for asylum (or refugee status for possible resettlement) by showing a reasonable fear that Ukraine would also extradite him to Russia or otherwise persecute him.

@phoog, what Evgeniy is looking for is a country which resists pressure both from NATO and Russia (both explicitly looking for him, as he mentions) and grants asylum to Ukrainians who were in Poland. I see no generic answer.

What if I give up my Ukrainian passport? Would it help?

This is off topic, you need to find a human rights group to advocate for you and help you. You're either a delusional individual or a known political figure and a good standard bearer for such groups. Either way here is not a place to disclose any sensitive details if you feel unsafe and persecuted and your case hinges on the details.

@Evgeniy, from my incomplete understanding of your personal situation, it would be extremely dangerous to reject your Ukrainian citizenship. There are plenty of special rules for Ukrainian refugees in the EU, and you should not put that special status into question.

A top official of a huge country used my phrases in a speech (in 2016), but I can't even get asylum in another huge country.

@Evgeniy, Expatriates Stack Exchange is not about fairness and justice. It is about the rules and regulations for living in another country. Your problem is not a good fit for a Q&A site.

Under what rules are you currently in Poland? Are you there legally? Are you able to work? Is it a long term visa or will you have to leave at some point?

@DJClayworth, Yes, legally. I can't write the details here, but in an exchange, the obligations of punishment are transferred to the other party. And since I have toxic encephalopathy, you can assume my situation.

Have you ever served in the military of either Ukraine or Russia? Have you talked to a lawyer in Poland?

@DJClayworth No. A lawyer will not help, I have written to every possible Russian and Ukrainian service, including letters to presidents. Because I was slandered, twisted what I said, as well as taken out of context. But since friends of high-ranking officials brought it to the top leadership of the country, they said that nothing could be done.

You can claim asylum in any country that you can get to. However being able to claim asylum does not mean that you will be granted it. The country where you claim asylum will decide if they will grant it or not.
You are already in Poland, so the logical thing to do is to do it there. Being legally resident in Poland you can also visit any country in the Schengen area, and have the opportunity to claim asylum in any of them. Since Poland and the rest of the Schengen countries, and the EU, have shared policies on immigration it is very unlikely that claiming asylum in another Schengen or EU country will have a different result from claiming asylum in Poland. If you have already tried to claim asylum in Poland and had it denied then no other country is likely to grant it to you. For a country outside Europe you will need to get at least a visitor visa for the country so that you can get there in order to claim asylum. As you have had a request rejected by the US this will obviously be very difficult.
You have a concern about being extradited to either Ukraine or Russia. Extradition can only legally occur if you have committed a crime. Your country of residence would have to be satisfied that there is reasonable evidence for the crime, and that you will get a fair trial. The process of establishing that is a legal one, and a lawyer will know what is the best way to defend yourself against it.
Alternatively it is possible that someone may try to convince the country you live in that you are undesirable and get them to deport you (this is different from extradition). That decision can be challenged in law, and a lawyer will know what is the best way to prevent it happening.

This is incorrect. The local authorities of the country decide whether to grant asylum or not. They reserve the right to refuse without giving a reason.

Yes, I know that and I said that. But they have to do it according to the law. A lawyer can help with that. Not having a lawyer will be a problem if you make an asylum claim. (I know this, I am involved with refugee claims in my country).

Since Poland and the rest of the Schengen countries, and the EU, have shared policies on immigration it is very unlikely that claiming asylum in another Schengen or EU country will have a different result from claiming asylum in Poland. EU law  does define a lot of rules on asylum (not so much immigration in general) but they are mostly procedural (who should process which application, right to an appeal, how forced returns should proceed, etc.) In practice, statistics show huge differences between countries in the success rate of asylum seekers from the same country.

Incidentally, Ireland and the UK had an opt-out from all this but Ireland just opted in earlier this year so these rule finally do cover the whole EU.
